# How to configure request in Postman, to gain access to xapi.xtb.com?

Tags: request, postman

I'm trying to create collection in Postman that will perform several requests to xapi.xtb.co API.
Documentation is available [here](http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/). Documentation is unclear, or I'm stupid (very possible).

1. I have a demo account.
2. I'm trying to send POST request at htps://xapi.xtb.com:5124. I've left headers at default. Body is a raw JSON and looks like this:

```
{
    "command": "login",
    "arguments": {
        "userId": "{{login}}",
        "password": "{{password}}"
    }
}
```

Documentation says nothing about any tokens, or any other way to authorize my request.

I'm getting only `socket hang up` error.

Does anybody use this API?

I was trying a GET request.
I was trying to use port 5112.